# Minimize $x^4+ \frac{1}{x^4} +y^4+ \frac{1}{y^4}$

Tags: algebra-precalculus, inequality, optimization, maxima-minima, jensen-inequality

> Minimize $${x^4+ \frac{1}{x^4} +y^4+ \frac{1}{y^4}}  $$
>   Subject to $$x^2+y^2=4$$

---

I've managed to solve this by substituting $x=(2+t)^\frac{1}{2}$ and $y=(2-t)^\frac{1}{2}$ and I arrived at a minimum of $\frac{17}{2}$ when $t=0$, but it's kind of tedious.
So I'm asking if there are straightforward ways of finding the minimum using inequalities and not using symmetry.

Comment: You could always use the lagrange multiplier method... https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lagrange_multiplier

Comment: @5xum but if you can write one of the variables as a function of others, you had better just plug the function. :)

Comment: $$x=2\cos t,y=2\sin t$$

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Let $f(x)=x^2+\frac{1}{x^2}$.

Thus, $f''(x)>0$.

Thus, by Jensen
$$x^4+\frac{1}{x^4}+y^4+\frac{1}{y^4}\geq2\left(\left(\frac{x^2+y^2}{2}\right)^2+\frac{1}{\left(\frac{x^2+y^2}{2}\right)^2}\right)=\frac{17}{2}.$$
The equality occurs for $x=y=\sqrt2$, which says that we got a minimal value.

Done!

Comment: @PotatoHead47 You are welcome!